# How a change the content size of a webview in android?

Tags: java, android, webview, scrollview

I have a webview control in a scrollview. when i load a long html document into it, it resizes to accommodate it. this is correct. however, when i use the same control again afterwards and put less space-consuming html into it, the content size doesn't shrink. this is a problem because the user is able to still scroll a short document into white space. any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: did you found a solution for this :(

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem and resolved it by clearing the view and re-measuring with a small size prior to loading the view again.

e.g.

```
  webView.clearView();
  webView.measure(10, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks, problem solved, but i cant accept your solution, button disappeared :(

Comment: This results in a the scrollbar glitching for me on a HTC Desire S on running 2.3.5.

Comment: This solution is not working for me on my Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.1.1.

Comment: This solution is not working for me on my HTC G20 running Android 4.0.3

Comment: This solution is not working for me on my Nexus 7 running Android 4.3

Answer (score 4):

This didn't work for me when using:

```
loadDataWithBaseURL(String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl)
```

But calling requestLayout() on the webview after loading the data worked except for a strange glitch with the scrollbar flickering if changing the view while scrolling.

```
webView.clearView();
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
webView.requestLayout();
```

Comment: you, sir, saved my life. *hats off*